# How to use SWIG %pointer_class with typedef types?

Tags: swig

If I have these two C++ files:

foo.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"

void foo(Foo* p) {};
```

foo.h:

```
class Foo {};

void foo(Foo*);
```

I can write this SWIG interface

```
%{
    #include "foo.h"
%}

%include <cpointer.i>
%pointer_class(Foo, Foop)

%include "foo.h"
```

compile, and call

```
>>>p = Foop()
>>>foo(p)
```

How do I write the interface if `Foo` is typedef instead

```
typedef int Foo;
```

so that I can do the same Python calls as above?

Comment: Have you tried without a typedef, directly with int? As in void foo(int*) {} and %pointer_class(int, intp) ?

Comment: Yes, but that's not what I want.  I need to write the interface to the typedef type.

Comment: I realize it's not what you want, I was just wondering if it works for you for the simple case of explicit int rather than typedef'd Foo to int. If it does, what you say implies that after you insert typedef int Foo in the two places in the .i, and change all occurrences of int for Foo, if you just make those simple changes and no more no less, it no longer works, is that correct?

Comment: @Schollii yes correct, if I don't typedef it works, if I use my own class it works, if I use a primitive types works, but if I use a typedef it does not work.

Comment: What doesn't work: swig says can't be done, or crashes, or swig OK but the code won't build, or code builds but you don't get behavior you want?

Comment: it says, Foop() undefined

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `%pointer_class` is meant to be used with a `typedef`.  SWIG considers a `typedef` the same as the original type and doesn't generate a wrapper for the typedef-ed name.  For example, SWIG only generates `Bar` for Python:

```
%module x

%inline %{
class Bar {};
typedef Bar Foo;
void foo(Foo* p) {};
%}
```

Output:

```
>>> import x
>>> x.Foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Foo'
>>> p=x.Bar()
>>> x.foo(p)
>>>
```

So I believe your case with `typedef int Foo;` and `%pointer_class(Foo, Foop)` doesn't work because the `Foo` wrapper doesn't exist.  I found that the below "trick" works for a `class` and an `int` if you use a `typedef` in both cases and use the same value for both parameters of `%pointer_class`:

```
%module x

%inline %{
  class Bar {};
  typedef Bar Foo;
  void foo(Foo* p) {};
%}

%include <cpointer.i>
%pointer_class(Foo, Foo)  // doesn't work if 2nd param doesn't match 1st.
```

And:

```
%module x

%inline %{
  typedef int Foo;
  void foo(Foo* p) {};
%}

%include <cpointer.i>
%pointer_class(Foo, Foo)  // doesn't work if 2nd param doesn't match 1st.
```

But if you really want an opaque type, don't let SWIG see the definition at all by only forward declaring the class and hiding the definition:

```
%module x

%inline %{
class Foo;
void foo(Foo* p);
%}

%include <cpointer.i>
%pointer_class(Foo, Foop)
```